# Timeout Error in Dojo When running .html page

Tags: dojo

I cannot get past this error in runtime in the browser.  I've got an html page running dojo and related javascript in it and every time I try to load the page, I get this in my Firebug console:

Error: timeout
makeError()dojo.js (line 106)
startTimer/timerId<()dojo.js (line 1500)

```
return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info});
```

referring to this line in the core dojo.js library:

```
makeError = function(error, info){
return mix(new Error(error), {src:"dojoLoader", info:info});
},
```

I also get this error:

```
Error: Could not load class 'gt.widget.HtmlContainer
[Break On This Error]   

if (eventData)
```

And at the bottom of this html page and for some reason it's saying in Webstorm `attribute "data-dojo-type" is not allowed here` although I see this kinda of setup in most of our other .html files and they do run:

```
...
    </script>
</head>
<body class="base">
    <div class="heading">Dependent Fields Data Test</div>
    <div id="container" data-dojo-type="gt.widget.HtmlContainer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No idea why it's timing out and why the loader is having any issue.  Here's a sample of the very first part of the .html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Unit Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../config-tests.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../toolkit/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require
        ([
            "dojo/ready",
            "dojo/on",
            "doh/runner",
            "gt/mvc/MvcInitializer",
            "gt/widget/HtmlContainer",
            "gt/util/runModeUtil",
            "gt/sub/topic",
            "gt/sub/coreTopics",
            "gt/tests/employee/employeeData"
        ], function (ready, on, runner, MvcInitializer, HtmlContainer, runModeUtil, topic, coreTopics, dependentData)
        {
            ready(function() 
            {
                var _topicHandle = null;
....
```

UPDATE

Now I'm also seeing errors like this when I run my .htm page in firefox:

absolutely clueless on this.  I have never used Dojo but this seems ridiculous.

```
Error in parsing value for 'font'.  Declaration dropped. C:/.../js/toolkit/dojox/widget/Toaster/Toaster.css:42 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/.../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/..../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/..../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/.../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/.../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///C:/..../js/toolkit/dojo/_base/xhr.js Line: 735"] 
Error: timeout 
src: dojoLoader 
info: [object Object] 
fileName: file:///C:/...../js/toolkit/dojo/dojo.js 
lineNumber: 106 
columnNumber: 3 
. 
Key event not available on some keyboard layouts: key="b" modifiers="accel,alt"
```

Comment: What happens if you strip everything out apart from the `container` div and the require for `gt/widget/HtmlContainer`?

Comment: Do you have to run the code from a web server rather than from file://? And those URLs don't look right to me `file:///C:/..../js/...`.

Comment: well originally I was using Aptana and just running the debugger which opens FireFox or Chrome, etc.  And the url was for example http://127.0.0.1:8020/........./tests/.../testData.html.  Now I'm using WebStorm which I like a lot and it run via a file url, e.g. file:///C:/Work/...../js/srcore/tests/dependent/testData.html.  Either way, I get the same errors either in Firebug or Webstorm.